# Is there a way to elegantly use a django model as an input object type?

Tags: graphene-django

Say I have,

```
class PersonNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'age',
                  'sex', 'alive', 'unique_identifier',)
        filter_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'age',
                         'sex', 'alive', 'unique_identifier',)
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)

class PersonNodeInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    first_name = graphene.String()
    last_name = graphene.String()
    # rest of person model fields

class Valid(graphene.ObjectType):
    ok = graphene.Boolean()

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    validate_person = graphene.Field(Valid, args={
                                     "data": PersonNodeInput()})
    person = graphene.relay.Node.Field(PersonNode)
    all_people = DjangoFilterConnectionField(PersonNode)

    def resolve_validate_person(root, info, data):
        print("resolve validate person")
        return Valid(ok=True)
```

Is it possible to avoid writing out PersonNodeInput?  It would be nice if you could subclass something like "DjangoInputObjectType" and specify the model and fields you want in a Meta attribute.

Answer (score 2):

We've been using this [Graphene Django CUD](https://graphene-django-cud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/usage.html) library that tries to remove some of the boilerplate involved in defining mutations.

Adapting your case to their example would look something like

```py
from graphene_django_cud.mutations import DjangoCreateMutation

class CreatePersonMutation(DjangoCreateMutation):
    class Meta:
        model = Person

class PersonMutations(graphene.ObjectType):
    create_person = CreateUserMutation.Field()

schema = Schema(mutation=PersonMutations)
```

I don't know how well it works with Relay nodes, because we're not using Relay.

Answer (score 1):

There is a PR in graphene-django https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/pull/1325 (Adds DjangoFormInputObjectType (InputObjectType derived class) which can retrieve fields from django form):

```py
class MyDjangoFormInput(DjangoFormInputObjectType):

    # any other fields can be placed here as well as
    # other djangoforminputobjects and intputobjects

    class Meta:
        form_class = MyDjangoModelForm


class SomeMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        data = MyDjangoFormInput(required=True)

    @staticmethod
    def mutate(_root, _info, data):
        form_inst = MyDjangoModelForm(data=data)
        if form_inst.is_valid():
            model_inst = form_inst.save(commit=False)

        # ...
```

Comment: This is now merged and published in graphene-django v3.1.1 (thanks ndpu!). Docs here https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/blob/2358bd30a452859c50b6bdacdc27ae518716153b/docs/mutations.rst#djangoforminputobjecttype

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check out the dicussion [here](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/121#issuecomment-422259823). charlesverdad's answer did the trick for me:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from graphene_django.rest_framework.serializer_converter import convert_serializer_to_input_type

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ('profile',)

class PersonArgsInput(convert_serializer_to_input_type(PersonSerializer)):
    create = graphene.Boolean(required=True)

class PersonsMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    person_set = graphene.List(PersonType)
    class Arguments:
        person_set = graphene.List(PersonArgsInput)
    def mutate():
        ...
```

I like this way because I use the Django serializer anyway. All credits to  Charles Verdad.